# rxjs and WebStorm

Tags: angular, rxjs, webstorm

After upgrading my Angular project to version 5.2.8 my WebStorm IDE (2017.3.5) does not recognize the rxjs operators (rxjs@5.5.6) anymore. It complains with `unresolved function or method`. The compilation (typescript@2.6.2) using angular cli still works.

In the following example it happens for the operator `do`

```
Observable.from([1,2])
     .do((i: number) =>  {
        console.log(i);
     })
```

It does not matter if I import the do operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';`in the same file or somewhere central.

Any idea how I have to configure WebStorm to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Starting with RxJS 5.5, they introduced [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), and as part of that, they switched from `do` to `tap` (so as not to conflict with a reserved JavaScript keyword).

To update your code, first change your imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then change your code to this:

```
Observable.from([1,2]).pipe(
  tap((i: number) =>  {
    console.log(i);
  })
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The change has nothing to do with WebStorm, but everything to do with the changes in the API for RxJS.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Since the build works I don't think it's a problem with rxjs. It also happens with many other operators like map or filter. I just recognized that the problem usually appears on the second operator in a chain of operators. That's why I still think that it's just a configuration issue with WebStorm - as if WebStorm did not know that the return type of the first operator was an Observable